# Adding words to game through PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game new words will be added all the time so there is always a fresh selection of words to spell.

Each word added to the game has a "src" to an image and a sound that will prompts the user into getting the spelling correct in gameplay.

When I have completed making the game, the job of adding the new words in is down to one of my colleagues. This means he will have to add a link for the pic and audio as well as the word.

As they have little knowledge with this sort of thing I want to make it as easy as possible for him to add the images and sounds when adding the words I want to create a default path to a shared location where he will store all this stuff.

This way he can just type in "bug" for the word, ".bug-pic" for the picture and ".bug-audio" for the sound making it simple for him to add into the HTML.

Is this the best way to do it?

What would be the simplest way for them to input these things?

Here is how I store the word, sound and image at the moment...

Comment: Hi. I've had a look at the jsfiddle but I'm struggling to reproduce the problem as I've understood from your desription. Can you set up a fork that doesn't include the random selection and reproduces the problem every run? I'm happy to have a look and see if we can sort it. S

Comment: The random produce is part of the problem though. I want it to take in to consideration whether it can fit where it is randomly placed. If not then go somewhere else. When I use just 3 letter words it works fine. @Scott Clark

Comment: That's cool, but I can't SEE the problem happening to understand fully as a start. Once it's taken care of you can reintroduce the random element of the process, no? Perhaps two options only for the resolution of the problem - one word of 3 letters and one of many that triggers the problem - then when they are both functioning you can re-include the whole 'game'...

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/pSLjy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the table with the letters that 'light up' indicating the word to be spelled is the bit we're trying to fix, right?

And you want the words to 'wrap' to the width of that table?

I see you're picking up data from each of the `<td>`s 'data-word=' attribute - which you could as easily attribute to a div in html5. Is there a particular reason it has to be a table? Otherwise, you could you use a wrapper div with fixed width and replace the `<td>`s with child divs set float:left - these would automatically 'wrap' regardless of where the last-in-line was respect to letters of any given word - i.e., it'd break words across new lines.

```
<style>
    .letters_wrap{
        width:500px;
        height:auto;
        ...
     }

     .letter{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        ...
    }

</style>

<div class="letters_wrap">
    <div class="letter" id="letter_1" data-word="shin">s</div>
    <div class="letter" id="letter_1" data-word="shin">h</div>
    <div class="letter" id="letter_1" data-word="shin">i</div>
    <div class="letter" id="letter_1" data-word="shin">n</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I've at least got the right end of the stick re what the probem is and what you're trying to achieve.

S

**UPDATE**

@m0onio - In the demo page I've bound the function to load the php file (and therefore the wordlist) to a button.

You would have the function execute in the `$(document).ready(){}` function making the javascript array containing the word list available once the DOM is available.

You need to write a javascript function (included before the closing `</body>` tag) to handle the construction of the child divs in the grid and call it from the callback function of the .load() that loads the php file (wordlist).

To attach the sounds and images, I'd include that info also in the txt file so the contents of the file would run: word | image filename | sound filename and then as you loop thru the array you know that every 1st element is the word, the 2nd the relevant image the 3rd the sound file etc. Then use jquery to append the resulting elements (the child divs) to it's parent container. Make sense?

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for to be honest, the only thing is you would need to be able to add new words through the html rather than through script @Scott Clark

Comment: @m0onio - thru' html would mean having user inputs which would then need to script to handle the new data entered (by the user or the admin?). Or do you mean new words have to be hard-coded into the html? In the meantime have a crack at building it with divs as above and then the addition of new words we can look at next. S

Comment: I mean for my colegues that would update the game. They said they would want to put new words in through html not in the script @Scott Clark

Comment: That's pretty ambiguous - to say 'put new words in through html' means to write it into the html code. For your sake I would clarify with them exactly how they want to update the game. My money's on... they want an interface - i.e., a page where they can edit a list of words then 'hit save' and those words will then become the list of words in the game. All very scriptable though.

Comment: From how you've structured your code, everything depends on the `<ul>` so that would have to be the dynamically updatable element to provide a UI for future word-list editing. You use mySql + php? - a database would do it obviously. Otherwise, you could load all the vars from a txt file - perhaps simpler - and then loop the creation of each `<li>`. In either scenario the 'admin page' would just allow the list to be viewed, check for keep or delete, create new item etc. then a script backend to overwrite the text file.

Comment: Ye a dynamically editable <ul> would be exacly what I am looking for. Unfortunately I have no experience with PHP or MySQL, is there any other way around it? How would this get around the grid overlapping problem though? @Scott Clark

Comment: Ah yes, the grid overlapping! we've digressed, no? If you were using the structure of divs we talked of earlier today you could easily adjust your code to pick out the data from the child divs and so consequently it would be the .letters_wrap div that would be populated with dynamically created child elements, i.e. .letter divs. In that way you could cover the data editing issue and the layout issue. If you need to have the word-list editable by 3rd party admin without re-coding the page then there would unavoidably be backend scripting handling it. @m0onio

Comment: Any chance you could start me off with a fiddle? Would help me to understand a bit more. Thanks @Scott Clark

Comment: @m0onio - go here... [doublecream.co.uk/m0onio/]http://www.doublecream.co.uk/m0onio/ - everything you need to load from a text file and output to javascript is in this demo, inc. instructions. Once you've implemented this as the method your game uses to load the wordlist then we can look at how to edit the wordlist. **This should be e new SO question now** - mark the first as answered if you're satisfied and then post the 'dynamic load vars from txt file' Q. - we'll carry on from there. S

Comment: Thanks Scott that is brilliant. How will the images and sounds be added to the words? @Scott Clark

Comment: _"This should be a new SO question now - mark the first as answered if you're satisfied and then post the 'dynamic load vars from txt file' Q. - we'll carry on from there."_  Sorry - don't want to seem pedantic, but this resource (SO) is invaluable so I'd rather try to follow form. ok? @me in the new Q post and we'll continue. All the best. S

Comment: How do I tag you in it? @Scott Clark